# add image and description on facebook with sharekit

Tags: facebook, sharekit

I am using sharekit to share text on facebook, i want to add a picture near the text like in this photo :

[image]

Any idea how to do this? and is there other suitable library like sharekit ? Thanks.

Comment: answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122414/sharekit-posting-linked-image-to-facebook-wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an og:image meta tag to your head html block.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlImage = @"some Image URL ";
    [item setCustomValue:urlImage forKey:@"image"];
```

//item is shareitem

Should get what you wanted.